# Mongo Secondary Sync Stuck in Recovery State

Tags: linux, mongodb

I have one master node and two secondary node. Due to some issues with one secondary node, it got stopped few days back. Now I am trying to resync the secondary node but after some time it goes into recovery state and stuck there.

For sync I deleted the data directory and restarted mongod service.

DB Size - 1.1 TB

```js
    sms3:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
 "set" : "sms3",
 "date" : ISODate("2015-09-01T08:33:40Z"),
 "myState" : 1,
 "members" : [
  {
   "_id" : 9,
   "name" : "abc:27117",
   "health" : 1,
   "state" : 1,
   "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
   "uptime" : 9415375,
   "optime" : Timestamp(1441096420, 7),
   "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-09-01T08:33:40Z"),
   "self" : true
  },
  {
   "_id" : 10,
   "name" : "def:27117",
   "health" : 1,
   "state" : 2,
   "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
   "uptime" : 9411728,
   "optime" : Timestamp(1441096418, 159),
   "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-09-01T08:33:38Z"),
   "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-09-01T08:33:38Z"),
   "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-09-01T08:33:39Z"),
   "pingMs" : 0,
   "syncingTo" : "db330.oak1.omniture.com:27117"
  },
  {
   "_id" : 11,
   "name" : "ghi:27117",
   "health" : 1,
   "state" : 3,
   "stateStr" : "RECOVERING",
   "uptime" : 53615,
   "optime" : Timestamp(1441042830, 300),
   "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-08-31T17:40:30Z"),
   "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-09-01T08:33:39Z"),
   "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-09-01T08:33:39Z"),
   "pingMs" : 0,
   "syncingTo" : "db330.oak1.omniture.com:27117"
  }
 ],
 "ok" : 1
}
```

```js
    sms3:PRIMARY> rs.config()
{
 "_id" : "sms3",
 "version" : 87615,
 "members" : [
  {
   "_id" : 9,
   "host" : "abc:27117"
  },
  {
   "_id" : 10,
   "host" : "def:27117",
   "priority" : 0.5
  },
  {
   "_id" : 11,
   "host" : "ghi:27117",
   "priority" : 0.5
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I synced the data directory on secondary node which was down from another secondary node which was up and restarted mongo.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your capped collection is gone out of sync. So you will need to clear everything from secondary and then restart the sync.